# Analysis feature of SOLR web admin

Tags: solr

I am wondering if I can use "analysis" feature of SOLR web admin (4.1) in my script. That is to get analyzed result given a string. I am guessing there should be some API that is utilized by the SOLR web admin

Or I would like to find a way to run an analyzer on some strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis Admin page is just leveraging the [AnaylsisRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalysisRequestHandler) behind the scenes to display the results. Please see the link for more details and an example.